# Codeigniter : How can call model funcation in View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

i have model and defined 2 function
1.getMember()
2. getMemberCommunity($member_id)

Controller code

```
 public function index($pass=null){                  
      $this->load->model('member_model');
      $data['query']=$this->member_model->getMember();       
      $this->load->view('backend/project',$data);
}
```

View

```
foreach($query as $row) {     
    // i want to call my another model function ? 
    //please give me any solutions ya tips   
}
```

Comment: why you want to do this ? you are breaking the framework structure. What exactly you want to do? Why you want to call your model in your view ?

Comment: @RickSmarty I think he maybe wants to do a `JOIN` in order to get the member community `foreach` member in the view.

Comment: Put your function in helper then call..

Comment: there is no need for that.CI is following MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this by joining the members table where the member id is equal to the member id in the member community table, I think this is what you want:

Model

```
public function getMembers(){                  

    $this->db->from('members')
             ->join('member_community', 'members.id = member_community.member_id', 'left');

    $members = $this->db->get();

    return $members;

}
```

Controller

```
public function index($pass=null){                  
    $this->load->model('member_model');
    $data['query']=$this->member_model->getMembers();       
    $this->load->view('backend/project',$data);
}
```

View

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {     
    // do whatever in here      
}
```